# How to push file for user download from third-party file

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a function in my app that uses an API call to push dynamic HTML to convert it to a PDF. The API returns a download URL.

What I want to do, ideally without download back to my server and serving locally, is to have the file immediately start downloading. I was able to do this with `send_file()` with local files, but not with files stored elsewhere.

My code is:

```
@app.route('/generatereport', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def generateReport():
    precords = people.find({"parentrecord": current_user.user_json['_id']}).sort('nextContact', pymongo.ASCENDING)
    todayDate = date.today()
    result = pdfgeneratorv2(info=precords, date=todayDate, user=current_user.user_json)

    return send_file(result, as_attachment=True)
```

and my pdfgeneratorv2 function is:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, select_autoescape, FileSystemLoader
from api2pdf import Api2Pdf
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv(dotenv_path='creds.env')

a2p_client = Api2Pdf(os.environ.get('Api2PdfKey'))


def pdfgeneratorv2(info, date, user):
    env = Environment(
        loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'),
        autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
    )
    template = env.get_template('ReportTemplate.html')
    html = template.render(records=info, todayDate=date, user=user)
    api_response = a2p_client.Chrome.html_to_pdf(html, file_name='Networking Report.pdf')

    print(api_response.result)

    return api_response.result['FileUrl']
```

help would be greatly appreciated!

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 290, in decorated_view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\VS Code Python\Flask Site\app.py", line 576, in generateReport
    return send_file(result, as_attachment=True)
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 537, in send_file
    return werkzeug.utils.send_file(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 440, in send_file
    stat = os.stat(path)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\David PC\\Desktop\\VS Code Python\\Flask Site\\https://URLREMOVED'
```

Comment: You'll need to URI encode a web address if you want to use that as a file or directory

Comment: Thanks! So I tried using `return urllib.parse.quote(api_response.result['FileUrl'])` in my `pdfgeneratorv2` function and it still gave same error.

Comment: Try `urllib.parse.urlencode`. But also, you have `file_name='Networking Report.pdf')`, so where is the redacted url coming from?

Comment: Different error this time! I didn't include full traceback but I can if relevant. `
    return urllib.parse.urlencode(api_response.result['FileUrl'])
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 944, in urlencode
    raise TypeError("not a valid non-string sequence "
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 937, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object`

Comment: Unfortunately, back to the original error :/

Comment: What exactly is the output from `print(api_response.result)`? Also, you do appear to be saving the file locally in the pdf function, so if you don't want to do that, you'll need to return a `io.BytesIO` object from send_file

Comment: There is no file saved locally as far as I am aware. The output is: `{'ResponseId': 'bd878e82-a42b-4b48-aeaa-2e510118a644', 'MbOut': 0.057297, 'Cost': 0.000266183275, 'Seconds': 1.025, 'Error': None, 'Success': True, 'FileUrl': 'URLREMOVEDFORPRIVACY'}`

Comment: So `URLREMOVEDFORPRIVACY` contains the filename you'd like to save as? Can you parse that value and just return the filename? Or, can you read that file content into BytesIO object?

Comment: Ideally, I do not want to save the file locally at all - I simply want to serve the file to the end-user as a download.

Comment: And yes - I can access the URL value w/ api_response.result['FileUrl']

Comment: Yes, I understood the question. From what I understand, you are required to download the file, or you need to instead return a 301 redirect from Flask for the browser to download it. However, I assume Api2Pdf requires your API key to download files, and looking at the docs, there's helper methods that allow you to do that. You can delete files from disk after the response is built

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247433/discussion-between-david-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: Your other option would be to use selenium webdriver and some other Python library to create the pdf bytes without any external service

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @OneCricketeer for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up solving this using BytesIO.

My `pdfgeneratorv2` function remained identical. My `generateReport` route was changed to:

```
@app.route('/generatereport', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
@limiter.limit("1/minute") # Maximum of 1 request per minute
def generateReport():
    precords = people.find({"parentrecord": current_user.user_json['_id']}).sort('nextContact', pymongo.ASCENDING)
    todayDate = date.today()
    result = pdfgeneratorv2(info=precords, date=todayDate, user=current_user.user_json)
    resp = requests.get(result)
    return send_file(BytesIO(resp.content), mimetype="application/pdf", download_name="Networking Report.pdf", as_attachment=True)
```

This also allows me to not have to delete the file afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you use `get(..., stream=True)` then `resp.raw` should give `file-like` object which you could use without `BytesIO`.  `send_file(resp.raw, ...)`

Comment: theoretically if `pdfgeneratorv2` gives URL in `result` then you could try `return redirect(result)` and browser may try to download it directly from other server.

Comment: @furas I think Api2Pdf with a redirect won't work because it has an api token

Comment: @furas I am trying to avoid a redirect, as I know my browser opens up PDFs in the current browser window meaning users would need to hit back button to go back to the app. The feature is a 'Download Report' button and so I want it to always download as a file. But yes the function does return the URL as the result.